# How to combine boost::shared_ptr and stl list

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm using stl `list` as `boost::shared_ptr`. E.g.:

```
#typedef boost::shared_ptr< std::list<SomeStruct> > list_ptr;
list_ptr list;
list_ptr otherlist;
```

now I want to merge the list into another. Default stl behavior is `list.merge(otherlist)`. But the compiler complains about it (no mathcing function) as long as I use `shared_ptr`

Now I figured out, that

```
list.merge(*(otherlist.get())
```

compiles.

Question: It this the way it has to be done or just my silly workaround?

Comment: Did you try `list.merge(*otherlist)`? In general, you use `*` to dereference pointers, smart or otherwise.

Comment: Yes I did, but not list->merge(*list2)

Comment: By `list` do you mean `list_ptr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both lists are held in shared pointers, you'd do this:

```
list1->merge(*list2);
```

The `->` is used instead of `.` to dereference the list1 pointer.  It's equivalent to this:

```
(*list1).merge(*list2);
```

Of course you'd remove the `*` in front of either list if it is not held in a smart pointer.